# php random array

Tags: php

I am trying to get a random array like this

```
srand((float) microtime() * 10000000);
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

it shows 2 numbers randomly if I have `$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);` but since I want all 5 to show it doesnt work. whats causing that. I need to use array_rand. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`array_rand` sorts the keys in the same order they exist in the original array. If you want a shuffled array, use the `shuffle` function first:

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
shuffle($input);
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rand_keys); $i++) {
    echo $input[$rand_keys[$i]] . "\n";
}
```

Of course, in the case where you access all five, there's no need to call `array_rand` at all, but if you're varying its second parameter, this will still work.

As an aside, calling the `srand` function is unnecessary—it's done for you as of PHP 4.2.

Comment: please read above carefully. I dont wanna use shuffle or I wouldnt be asking question

Comment: @user295189: Why don't you want to use `shuffle`?

Answer (score 0):

changelog of this function :

```
5.2.10   The resulting array of keys is no longer shuffled.
```

this function doesn't return elements in random order, it returns random elements.
So if you want to get 5 random elements from your array, it just gets you all elements.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want use shuffle on original array, because it rearranges keys? If so, then just shuffle array with random keys, leaving input array unchanged.

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
shuffle($rand_keys);
print_r($rand_keys);
/**
 * Sample output
 Array
 (
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
 )
 */
```